# Boost Spirit and Boost Phoenix questions

Tags: c++, functional-programming, dsl, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

**one.** Is it possible to define that a spirit rule's local variable be default constructed using a parameter passed into the rule ? I have AST builder objects that have a cyclic dependency, I would like to initialize the child with a reference to the parent, the parent is passed by reference to 
the child parser's rule. Example: `rule< Iterator, void(Parent & p), locals<child> > child_parser;`

Note: there are ways of doing what I want above. I am only interested in the particular approach I have stated above, as it is the cleanest way of doing it.

**two**. How does one pass a pointer to a lazy phoenix placeholder ? it can't be as simple as `&_r1` or `&arg1`

Note: This question has been asked seperately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211894/boost-phoenix-or-boost-lambda-taking-pointer-lazily), you could answer it there.

**three.** How is the lambda / phoenix merger going, any idea when the merger will take place ?

p.s., thanks in advance for answering my question Hartmut :D

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that Stack Overflow works best with just one question per post. It lets people provide more focused answers, it lets you select the best answer for each distinct question, and it lets the questions have more descriptive titles to help later people find the posts they need. Please make three separate posts for these questions.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. However, point one and two are far too closely intertwined to split up into a separate question. Point three is trivial to answer and isn't a programming question.

Comment: Actually, there is value in question two on its own. I'll create a seperate question and reference it from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) There is no way of doing this, although it's a nice idea and worth investigating.
2) Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211894/boost-phoenix-or-boost-lambda-taking-a-pointer-lazily)
3) The mini-review of Phoenix V3 has ended March 2nd, the results have been published [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/66383).