# Boost Phoenix (or Boost Lambda) - taking a pointer lazily

Tags: c++, functional-programming, boost-lambda, boost-phoenix

Is there a way of taking a pointer of a lazy phoenix value / ref ? If so how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phoenix placeholders overload `operator&()`, therefore a simple `&_1` should do the trick (see Phoenix docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/composite.html#phoenix.composite.operator.supported_operators)).

Comment: Wow I'm surprised that it is indeed that simple :D